# Scrabble helper in bash

Tags: grep, wildcards, brace-expansion

I'm trying to make a scrabble helper in bash, which when given a list of characters, finds all the words in the `/usr/share/dict/words` file.
For example, when given the letters `a,c,r,t`
The word `cart` will match
The word `car` will also match
The word `carat` will **not** match

However, if `a,a,c,r,t` were given
Then `carat` would have matched.

I am trying to find if it is possible only using `grep`, I suspect that brace expansions like
`{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}` might be useful to generate all the possible combinations of the letters but instead I am greeted with the errors like

```
grep: aaac: No such file or directory
grep: aaar: No such file or directory
grep: aaat: No such file or directory
```

when running the command
`$ grep {a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t} /usr/share/dict/words`

When I use quotes like `"{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}"` or `"\{a,c,r,t\}\{a,c,r,t\}"`, brace expansion does not work at all

I know that the above command should not work as a scrabble helper but the errors are still rather unexpected. What is wrong with the command and how do I fix it? Also, can `grep` be used some way to make a scrabble helper at all?

Comment: Maybe awk with a length requirement and pattern matches for each letter?

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are not the best tool for this kind of job. I'd do something like:

```
perl -CLASD -lne '
  BEGIN{$l0{$_}++ for (split "", shift)}
  %l = %l0; for (split "") {next LINE unless $l{$_}--}
  print' aacrt < /usr/share/dict/words
```

Or since (at least in French and English [and some other languages using the latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions)), scrabble only has the 26 uppercase letters A to Z (été is written as ETE, cœur as COEUR), with GNU `iconv`:

```
iconv -t us//TRANSLIT < /usr/share/dict/words |
  perl -CLASD -lne '
    BEGIN{$l0{$_}++ for (split "", uc shift)}
    %l = %l0; for (split "", uc $_) {next LINE unless $l{$_}--}
    print' croeu
```

Or to output in the original form:

```
perl -CLASD -MText::Unidecode -lne '
  BEGIN{$l0{$_}++ for (split "", uc shift)}
  %l = %l0; for (split "", uc unidecode $_) {next LINE unless $l{$_}--}
  print' croeu < /usr/share/dict/word
```

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is that the  `{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}` is expanded by shell you are using. That means the first of those (`aaaa`) is the pattern that `grep` will search on `aaac`, `aaar`, etc., as if you typed:

```
grep aaaa aaac aaar aaat aaca ..... /usr/share/dict/words
```

Put the search pattern in single quotes to prevent this from happening:

```
grep '{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}{a,c,r,t}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

On the on the other hand, I am not sure if you using the right syntax for grep here. I would use:

```
grep '[acrt][acrt][acrt][actr]' /usr/share/dict/words
```

which matches those combinations of 4 characters, and as @mueh commented:

```
grep -xE '[acrt]{1,4}' /usr/share/dict/words
```

to match 1-4 combinations of those letters.

Comment: I tried double quotes with and without escaping which didn't work. I just tried your single quotes suggestion which also doesn't return any result strangely. I would expect words like `cart` or `scratch` or `carts` or `cartoon` to pop up...

Comment: @AvZ Didn't look at the actual output. I updated the answer with a form that will give results (`[]` specifying a set of characters to match in regex matching)

Comment: I'd suggest `'^[acrt]{1,4}$' ` as the OP wants to match "car" for example too.

Comment: Very strange, I understand how `'^[acrt]{1,4}$'` should be sufficient but it doesn't return any result!

Comment: There is also the fact that `'^[acrt]{1,4}$'` will also match with `aaaa` (repetition) which is undesired in a scrabble helper, can that be prevented?

Comment: @AvZ `'^[acrt]{1,4}$'` is extended regexp, for that you need to specify `grep -E '^[acrt]{1,4}$' /usr/share/dict/words`. Not sure how you can prevent the repetition.

Answer (score 2):

Bash expansion of curly braces does not generate valid permutations as the set includes items with same character repeats and missing character in some.

What you need is some anagram tool that will use all or some of the characters. Fortunately such tool already exists as part of standard Linux. It is called **an**. It uses **/usr/share/dict/words** as its default dictionary.

Here is an example of how you can use it.

First define this function (interactively will do):

```
$ mywords() { an -w "$1" -m 4 | awk '/^[a-z]*$/ {print length($0), $0}' | column; }
```

Now suppose you have these letters ypltar. To find valid dictionary words that have all or some of them use:

```
$ mywords ypltar
6 partly        5 party         4 tray          4 tarp          4 pray          4 part
6 paltry        5 aptly         4 trap          4 rapt          4 play          4 arty
```

I have used -m 4 in the function to limit the output words to those that have no fewer than 4 letters. You can change that as you need. The awk bit is to exclude dictionary entries with capital letters (proper names etc).

Answer (score 0):

So, my playing with this got me to generate this script, which gives the 3, ..., n letter words. It has issues in that letters can appear more than once - 'WordGuess stop' will return oops and toot as well as pots and post.
Still working to clean it up.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# WordGuess - an attempt at automated word generation for 
# anagrams and word finds
# 2024-02-02 SRJ
#
WordList="/usr/share/dict/american-english"
Argument="${@}"
Length=${#Argument}

# Double this to start properly with 3 character strings below
String="[${Argument}][${Argument}]"

for ((i = 2; i < ${Length}; i++)) ; do
    String="${String}[${Argument}]"
    echo -n $(grep -E "^${String}$" ${WordList})" "
echo
done
```

When run;

```
WordGuess stop
ops opt pop pot sop sos sot too top tot tsp oops opts
poop pops poss post pots psst soot sops sots spot stop toot tops toss tost tots
```

I think the proper way to do this would be to generate every permutation and try to grep that from the word list, but that would be slow.